# Validation for null values in view using jquery

Tags: jquery, razor

Below is my code and i need to validate the below code for null values that means if model is not null then only i need to execute the below line.

```
var text = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.results.Select(x => new { x.source, x.destination, x.Id})));
```

I have used

```
if(@model.reults != null)  but this piece of code is not working
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `@Model.results` within Razor a number of ways:

```
<script type='javascript'>
@if (Model.results != null) 
{
    var text = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.results.Select(x => new { x.source, x.destination, x.Id})));
} 
else 
{
    var text = "";
}
```

(which is a bit long-winded with all the enforced-on-single-line-brackets in Razor)

Note that `var text =` will only be output once as the `@if else` is run server-side.

Alternatively:

```
<script type='javascript'>
var text = @Html.Raw(Model.results != null 
                     ? Json.Encode(Model.results.Select(x => new { x.source, x.destination, x.Id})) 
                     : ""
           );
```

Both of these require a `<script>` tag inside the .cshtml - they can't be in a .js file as .js files are not parsed for Razor.